# What are the cosets of this presentation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I'm reading a book on algebra, and they give a presentation for $S_3$, with 6 elements $\{1, x, x^2, y, x y, x^2y\}$ as $$x^3 = 1,\quad y^2 = 1,\quad y x=x^2y$$

Now later in the book, there is a subgroup $H = \{1, x y\}$.  So they give the left cosets of $H$ in this group as

$$\{1, x y\} = H = xyH$$
$$\{x, x^2 y\} = xH = x^2yH$$
$$\{x^2 y\} = x^2H = yH$$

The last set of equations is what concerns me.  I think it should be 
$$\{x^2, y\} = x^2H = yH$$  Am I correct?  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: You're right. Since the cosets partition the group, you need to have all six values somewhere. If it wasn't your way, you would only have 5 of the 6 group elements, so where did the last one go? It's also a theorem that all of the cosets of H in G have the same number of elements, so they should all have two elements.

Comment: @Tyler:  Thanks - that's a relief.  I was worried that I was missing a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As confirmed by Tyler in the comments, you are correct. What appears in the book is missing a comma.